# Firefox error on Centos 6.7 that node

Tags: linux, firefox, libraries

When opening Firefox via the Terminal in CentOS 6.7, I notice the following error:

```
console.error: 
  [CustomizableUI]
  Custom widget with id loop-button does not return a valid node
console.error: 
  [CustomizableUI]
  Custom widget with id loop-button does not return a valid node
console.error: hma_ext: 
  Message: [Exception... "An engine with that name already exists!"  nsresult: "0x80520008 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/components/nsSearchService.js :: FAIL :: line 278"  data: no]
console.error: hma_ext: 
  Message: [Exception... "An engine with that name already exists!"  nsresult: "0x80520008 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/components/nsSearchService.js :: FAIL :: line 278"  data: no]
console.error: self-destructing-cookies: 
  localstorage: 
  Component returned failure code: 0x804b000a (NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI) [nsIIOService.newURI]
```

I downloaded Firefox 4... and it installed a lot of library files, other files, and a couple of executables. The new Firefox download worked in that location, which was in the /home/../Downloads/ folder. When I moved it to the /usr/bin/ directory, it replaced the old Firefox but did not launch. I then decided to move / replace these library files that installed with Firefox with my current /lib64/ and /usr/share/lib64/ files.

Now, I cannot log into any user profile. I used a Live CD to backup my files successfully. Now, I want to know if I can simply flush the /lib64/ and /usr/share/lib64/ directories and download the default library folders for CentOS 6.7, or it is more practical to simply reinstall CentOS 6.7 since I have my data. Your thoughts?

Comment: Did you install Firefox with yum?

Comment: I ran Firefox via the Terminal and saw the errors displayed there.

Answer (score 0):

First check to see if you already have Firefox installed using **yum**

> sudo yum list firefox

Should yield:

> Installed Packages
>
> firefox.i686  38.5.0-2.el6.centos @updates

If **yum** doesn't have Firefox in its list of packages, install it with:

> sudo yum install firefox

This will install the ESR (extended support release) version

Unless you need the latest version, I recommend you use ESR

Comment: Do you have a desktop installed?

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this was to use Ubuntu as my native installation. I installed the Ubuntu Desktop. I still have some errors with Firefox, but I will create a question if I do not find the answer. I have CentOS 6.7 as my virtual drive.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is firefox setting issue, the loop.enabled has to be true

```
    firefox -v
    Mozilla Firefox 38.4.0

    with firefox url space
    about:config


    loop.enabled  set to true from false
```